# How do I escape HTML elements in C# .NET using JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

Consider this code:

```
// Dictionary created.

Dictionary<string, string> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string test = "<>";
objDic.Add("html", test);

var Json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string response = Json.Serialize(return_obj);
```

Output response:

```
[{"html":"\u003c\u003e"}]
```

Expected response:

```
[{"html":"<>"}]
```

How do I get the expected response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you can use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {html="<>"}) //returns {"html":"<>"}
```